# What does it mean by "get out there"?

Tags: meaning

I'm watching a program from VOA [from here](http://v.youku.com/v_show/id_XMzQ2MjI4Mzg0.html). In the 48th second of the video, there is a sentence:

> I can't wait to get out there!

I'm confused about this sentence. Does it mean "I will ***get out from there and will go to some other place***" or "I will ***get out from some place and will go to there***"?

Thanks.

---

Edit:

Can I use ***get out*** followed with a place, e.g.:

> I want to get out school.
>
> I want to get out this room.

Answer (score 2):

It would normally mean that the speaker was impatient to go to whatever place it was that had been brought to his attention.

Answer (score 2):

In response to your edit:

That wouldn't be proper. In this case, *get out there* just refers to a place that happens to be considered outside, and in a general area. You wouldn't say, “I can't wait to get out there to the movie theater!” because it's an inside attraction that you know the exact location of in order to be considered distinctly there.

For your example, you would say “I want to get out *of* this room”, to put room as the subject to get out of.

Answer (score 1):

In the context of the video, which appears to be an English lesson (美语 = "Beautiful Words"?) aimed at a Chinese audience, "I can't wait to get out there" simply indicates that the speaker is so happy and brimming with so much energy and enthusiasm that she is eager to get out and face whatever this beautiful day may bring.